# LibreCalc Absolute Cell References Changing

Tags: linux, libreoffice

Using Libre Office 6.3.0.4, Linux Mint 19.2, Flatpak release.

I have a simple function that needs to have a static row: `=K15-G$2`. Not sure when the error started occuring, but after I inserted (3) rows above row #2, the function changed to `=K15-G$5`. If I copy/move this function, the original values remain as expected. I tried modifying it to read `=K15-$G$2`, but that made no difference.

In this case, how can I get absolute cell references to work?

Comment: `=K15-$G$2` should have worked, according to [the documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Addresses_and_References,_Absolute_and_Relative); are you sure it didn't do the right thing?

Comment: (assuming `G2` is the absolute cell you're trying to get to, that is)

Comment: Positive - that's what's so weird, especially with this being such a simple formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localc` is working as documented (and as it should, and as every spreadsheet has done since the days of [Visicalc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet#VisiCalc)).

It's a feature, not a bug.

Your formula referred to cell `G$2`.  You inserted rows which moved `G$2` to `G$5` so `localc` updated all references to the old `G$2` to its new location of `G$5`, preserving the reference to the same data.

In short: the cell was moved so ALL references to it had to be updated to match its new location.

This needs to happen whether the reference was relative or absolute - the important thing is the data the reference was pointing to.

If it didn't do this, then every time a column or row was inserted or deleted, every formula referring to any cell that got moved as a result of that operation would be **broken because it would be pointing to the wrong data**.

The same thing happens when you **cut** and paste a cell from one location to another - if any formulae refer to it, they are updated to refer to the new location.   This allows you to move a cell or multiple cells to a different location on a sheet or even to a completely new sheet.

BTW, if you had inserted rows **below** `G$2` then `G$2` would **not** have been moved and there would be no need to update any references to it.  This happens frequently when you need to insert a row or rows between two existing rows in a table.  Or when you sort the data in a table.

Comment: OK, this makes sense.